# Problem with http 'POST' request

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

I am running in a stupid problem. I have an method which returns initialized request resposible for loggin in on some external web site.

```
protected HttpWebRequest GetLoginRequest()
{
    const string url = "https://someurl.com/login";

    var queryParams = new ArrayList
                          {
                              String.Format("{0}={1}", "email", Email),
                              String.Format("{0}={1}", "password", DecryptedPassword)
                          };

    var parameters = String.Join("&", (String[])queryParams.ToArray(typeof(String)));

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = parameters.Length;
    request.Timeout = 10000;

    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
    streamWriter.Write(parameters);
    streamWriter.Close();

    return request;
}
```

I'm calling this method from two places in my code. First call looks like that:

```
var request = GetLoginRequest();

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

And the second one has CookieContainer assigned to request:

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

var request = GetLoginRequest();
request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

because I need to store CookieContainer.

The thing is that the logon is performed only in second case. In the first case i'm getting response from the login page. I've checked all the cases and both resulting requests seem identic. I would suggest that it is target site secific, but still I don't see any reason for that.

**Can you please explain what is the reason, because this behavior seems pretty unobvious to me.**

Comment: the question seems entirely unrelated to the title

Comment: I'm sorry - at the first point I though that the problem is in content type passed, and I've forgot to change the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the `CookieContainer` property on your request, the response is populating that `CookieContainer` instance with the cookies received from the executed request.

Most login mechanisms use a cookie to store the state related to the established login. I.e. in the case of Forms authentication the cookie is the container for the forms authentication ticket. The ticket is passed as the value of the forms authentication cookie with each request and is used by forms authentication, on the server, to identify an authenticated user.

In short you need a `CookieContainer` for each request after you login, and it needs to contain the forms authentication cookie that you received when you logged in.

Edit to clarify comment - from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx):

> CookieContainer   is null by default.
>   You must assign a CookieContainer
>   object to the property to have cookies
>   returned in the Cookies property of
>   the HttpWebResponse returned by the
>   GetResponse method.
>
> **For security reasons, cookies are disabled by default. If you want to
>   use cookies, use the CookieContainer
>   property to enable cookies.**

Comment: It's clear. I thought empty CookieContainer instance is created by default request constructor. Does it means that when I'm not specifying CookieContainer explicitly, request does not accept cookies ? That's an weird behavior. So as I've understood your post when I'm not specifying CookieContainer, after authentification is performed the distant website app fails to store cookies in my request data and that's why I'm receiving LoginPage response?

Comment: @danyloid: CookieContainer is `null` by default - you have to create and assign one - clarified in my answer